# Fastlane Apple Developer account credentials

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

we are manually running fastlane right now as we have not setup CI/CD on a server yet.  The new developer ran our fastfile and was prompted to enter the passphrase we are using for match.  So he entered the passphrase, which worked fine, but next it prompted him to enter the password of that apple account which leads me to my question.

The account has admin access in the apple portal and we don't want everybody knowing the login credentials. Is there a way that a developer can run match without knowing the password to that apple account so we can prevent people from having access to a login with admin permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastlane `match` will not require passwords if you use `readonly`.

According to [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/)

> If you decide to run match without access to the Developer Portal, make sure to use the --readonly option so that the commands don't ask you for the password to the Developer Portal.

Comment: But once i run fastlane match import with --readonly, it is asking my password anyway